# My JavaScript program is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble with my code. The question reads as follows:

> **Create a Web page that you can use to calculate miles per gallon.**
>
> 1. Add a form to the Web page that contains four text  elements: starting mileage, ending mileage, gallons used, and miles
>      per gallon. Assign initial starting values of 0 to each of the 
>      element’s value attribute.
> 2. Add onchange event handlers to the starting mileage, ending mileage, and gallons used text boxes that call a JavaScript function
>      named calcMPG().
> 3. Create the calcMPG() function in a script section in the document head. Within the calcMPG() function,declare three variables,
>      startMiles, endMiles, and gallons, and initialize each variable with
>      the value assigned to the starting mileage, ending mileage, and
>      gallons.
> 4. Create an if . . . else statement that uses the isNaN() function within a compound conditional expression to determine whether the
>      startMiles, endMiles, and gallons variables contain numeric values.
> 5. If the variables do not contain numeric variables, display an alert dialog box informing the user that he or she must enter numeric
>      values. If the variables do contain numeric values,the else clause
>      should perform the miles-per-gallon calculation and assign the result
>      to the Miles per Gallon text box in the form.
> 6. The formula for calculating miles per gallon is (ending_mileage - starting_ mileage) / gallons*

This is the what I've got but it isn't working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calcMPG(){
   var startMiles = document.economy.startMilage.value;
   var endMiles = document.economy.endMilage.value;
   var gallons = document.economy.galonsUsed.value;


   if (isNaN(startMiles) = false)   
   {
      window.alert("You can only enter numbers") 
   }        }
   else 
   {
      document.mpg = document.write((endMiles - startMiles) / gallons) 
   }

}
</script>

<form name="economy">
<p>Starting Milages
<input type="text" name="starMilage" class="input" onchange="calcMPG()" /></p>
<p>Ending Milages
<input type="text" name="endMilage" class="input" onchange="calcMPG()" /></p>
<p>Galons Used
<input type="text" name="galonsUsed" class="input" onchange="calcMPG()" /></p>
<p>Miles Per Galon
<input type="text" name="mpg" class="input" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Please define "it aint working". What do you expect to happen and what happens instead? No result? Wrong results? Error messages in the Javascript console? Always? Sometimes?

Comment: To start with you have an extra closing brace on the line after window.alert()

Comment: Sorry but "Ain't working" is an extremely poor problem description. This is a site to ask actual questions, not to dump code and get it diagnosed and fixed.

Comment: i could see you closed the function just between the if and else.. :)

Comment: Syntax error. `function(){ if(){} } else { } }` isn't going to work

Comment: It has so many wrongs, I suggest you go through a JS tutorial, patiently.

Comment: The Javascript error console will allow you to see and debug your program, and would have caught a lot of these errors. Here's how to open it in [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console), [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#opening_the_console), and [Safari](http://gardengnomesoftware.com/wiki/Using_The_Browser_Error_Console#Safari).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `if (isNaN(startMiles) = false)` by `if (isNaN(startMiles))`

Remove `}` after `else`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calcMPG(){
   var startMiles = document.economy.startMilage.value;
   var endMiles = document.economy.endMilage.value;
   var gallons = document.economy.galonsUsed.value;

   if (isNaN(startMiles))   
   {
      window.alert("You can only enter numbers") 
   }      
   else 
   {
      document.mpg = document.write((endMiles - startMiles) / gallons) 
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You are right, corrected

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to do:

```
if (isNaN(startMiles) = false)
```

isNaN returns true or false depending on the condition.

```
if(isNaN(startMiles))   is enough.
```

Comment: It's not only "don't need to", the first will throw an error due to an invalid left-hand assignment.

Answer (score 0):

should be :

Remove `}` before `else` and also put `;` after  `alert`  and `document.write`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calcMPG(){
   var startMiles = document.economy.startMilage.value;
   var endMiles = document.economy.endMilage.value;
   var gallons = document.economy.galonsUsed.value;

   if (isNaN(startMiles))   
   {
       window.alert("You can only enter numbers");
   }       
   else 
   {
       document.mpg = document.write((endMiles - startMiles) / gallons);
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `isNaN(startMiles) = false` throws an error too.

Comment: ohhh sorry it was my mistake. it will not throws error.

Comment: you can't assign false to isNaN(startMiles)

Answer (score 0):

1. if you are using firefox, please install **FireBug**: https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/firebug/

   if you prefer chrome, you don't have to install anything.
2. press `F12` *(thanks @Christoph)*
3. look at the the console: You will see a lot of errors. Please, solve them before, as we are not here to compile code for you.

Comment: actually, it's F12 for both browsers... ;)